# SQLite query fails when MySQL query works

Tags: mysql, sqlite

When I use this query in MySql, it works :

```
SELECT spot_lat AS lat, spot_lng AS lng, city, place AS title, wiki_img, wiki_url, id AS spot_id, categorie, period
                FROM MY_TABLE 
                WHERE
            (CASE WHEN 42.7394 < 45.14886
                        THEN spot_lat BETWEEN 42.7394 AND 45.14886
                        ELSE spot_lat BETWEEN 45.14886 AND 42.7394
            END) 
            AND
            (CASE WHEN 5.1278 < 6.1278
                        THEN spot_lng BETWEEN 5.1278 AND 6.1278
                        ELSE spot_lng BETWEEN 6.1278 AND 5.1278
            END)
```

The same one in SQLite fails (retrieves no data).

Can someone explain me why ?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason why the same query works in MySQL but fails in SQLite is due to the difference in how these database systems handle the `CASE` statement.

In MySQL, the `CASE` statement evaluates the conditions and returns the corresponding result. In your query, when the condition `42.7394 < 45.14886` is true, it executes the first `THEN` clause, and when the condition is false, it executes the second `THEN` clause. This behavior allows you to dynamically adjust the range conditions based on the comparison results.

However, in SQLite, the `CASE` statement behaves differently. It evaluates the conditions but returns the result of the first matching condition. In your query, when the condition `42.7394 < 45.14886` is true, it evaluates the first `CASE` expression and returns the result of `spot_lat BETWEEN 42.7394 AND 45.14886`. If the condition is false, it evaluates the second `CASE` expression and returns the result of `spot_lat BETWEEN 45.14886 AND 42.7394`. This behavior doesn't dynamically adjust the range conditions based on the comparison results as in MySQL.

To make the query work in SQLite, you can modify it to use separate `OR` conditions instead of the `CASE` statement. Here's an example:

```sql
SELECT
  spot_lat AS lat,
  spot_lng AS lng,
  city,
  place AS title,
  wiki_img,
  wiki_url,
  id AS spot_id,
  categorie,
  period
FROM
  MY_TABLE
WHERE
  (42.7394 < 45.14886 AND spot_lat BETWEEN 42.7394 AND 45.14886)
  OR (42.7394 >= 45.14886 AND spot_lat BETWEEN 45.14886 AND 42.7394)
  AND (5.1278 < 6.1278 AND spot_lng BETWEEN 5.1278 AND 6.1278)
  OR (5.1278 >= 6.1278 AND spot_lng BETWEEN 6.1278 AND 5.1278);
```

In this modified query, separate `OR` conditions are used to handle the ranges based on the comparison results. This approach provides the desired behavior in SQLite similar to what you had in MySQL.

Please note that this modification assumes the conditions `42.7394 < 45.14886` and `5.1278 < 6.1278` are fixed and not dynamic. If you need dynamic conditions, you may need to adjust the query accordingly.